# Should IDataErrorInfo.Error return all of the errors?

Tags: .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should INotifyDataErrorInfo.GetErrors(null) return all of the errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542824/should-inotifydataerrorinfo-geterrorsnull-return-all-of-the-errors)

Should IDataErrorInfo.Error return all of the errors? Or should it return just the object level errors?

Comment: I *believe* should be merged into one if possible... in any case, perhaps add a bit more details, such as what various sources have to say.

Comment: They are different interfaces. They don't necessarily work the same way.

Comment: Are you encountering a specific problem with IDataErrorInfo.Error that you can elaborate on?

Comment: No, I just want to know how to use it right.

Comment: @Jonathan Allen: So you haven't tried to figure it out on your own?

Answer (score 0):

System.Data.DataRowView.DataRowView only exposes object level errors from IDataErrorInfo.Error, but I don't have any collaborating evidence.