# Should INotifyDataErrorInfo.GetErrors(null) return all of the errors?

Tags: silverlight

Should INotifyDataErrorInfo.GetErrors(null) return all of the errors? Or should it return just the object level errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifydataerrorinfo.geterrors%28v=vs.95%29.aspx):

> Parameters
>
> propertyName Type: System.String The name of the property to retrieve
> validation errors for; or null or Empty, to retrieve entity-level
> errors.

So object level it is.